# Are these numbers Madelung constants?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I have no idea of chemistry, just a little bit what I know from school, but I found through some search some connection between entropy (Shannon entropy) of the divisors of some natural numbers and the Madelung constants.

My question is this:

Are these numbers Madelung constants?

```
1 -0.000000000000000
2 1.38629436111989 ( http://oeis.org/A016627 )
3 1.38629436111989
4 3.31573052232910 
5 1.38629436111989
6 5.54531864369184  ( http://oeis.org/A257872 )
7 1.38629436111989
8 5.57849454296371
9 3.29975689063759
10 5.54521210457048
11 1.38629436111989
12 10.7943529563000
13 1.38629436111989
14 5.54518969515687
15 5.54519368543309
16 8.08924328274917
17 1.38629436111989
18 10.7599543952466
19 1.38629436111989
20 10.7921021686465
```

Thanks for your help!

Related question:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346239/entropy-magnitude-diversity-of-finite-metric-spaces-in-number-theory

**Edit**:
I think I found an explanation for the numbers ( entropy ). It is approximately:

$\tau(n) \log(\tau(n))$, where $\tau(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$.

So the $1.386$ and $5.545$ are just coincidences with Madelung constants I think.

Comment: 1.386 is 2log2 but what about 5.545 the closet approximation is 7log7 which is still 5.91. Am i missing something?

Comment: $5.545=8 \log(2)$ see the oeis link which relates this number to one Madelung contant

Comment: Ok i was mistaking that both the numbers inside and outside the log must be the same

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this would be very helpful or not but as i had some free time on hand I got a list of Madelung Constant Values from the [Internet](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Yehia_Khalil3/post/Please_help_I_need_the_values_of_the_Madelung_constants_and_or_Madelung_energies_for_BaCl2_Cr2O3_and_ZrO2_Do_you_know_where_to_find_them/attachment/59d64a8079197b80779a4c7e/AS%3A475541108203521%401490389243650/download/Madelung+Constants+and+Madelung+Energies.pdf)

In the list most of values were reported to 3-4 decimal places so I have Compared only the first decimal places as once the second decimal place was used none of the values matched. Maybe this would be a helpful start.

$$M_a$$ of ZnS (Wurtzite Hexagonal) is $10.7153$ (nearby the 12th and 18th entry in your table)

As Oscar Lanzi has commented $1.386$ is approximately $$2\log(2)$$ which is the Madelung constant for a one-dimensional line of alternating charges

As the question has been edited to add further details maybe the second one is a coincidence.

### **Only Nearby Matches So Far**

Comment: The $1.386$ figure is $2\log 2$, which is the Madelung constant for a one-dimensional line of alternating charges.

Comment: @OscarLanzi should i add this into my answer or are you going to write one on your own?

Comment: I say add it in.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Done